Finance question for US visa
I get a salary paycheck from my father's personal account, who is also the owner of the business we own. I am on a manager visa. Due to insufficient funds in my current account, we usually get my salary from his personal account. Can I get a payslip on the company letterhead mentioning my salary, even though it comes from his personal account?

How does the company account for your pay in its financial records if the money for your salary doesn’t come out of its bank account? You might need to provide your tax return as well

Paying company expenses out of a personal account is going to cause trouble elsewhere, but that's a question for another day.

Can filling the g639 form on the uscis for accessing my i94 record have an impact on my future visa applications
